# Perfect Hash Function for Human Readable Order Codes

Tags: php, encoding, hash

I am trying to generate non-sequential human readable order codes derived from (lets say) a unsigned 32bit internal id that starts at 1 and is auto incremented for each new order.

In my example code below, will every `$hash` be unique? (I plan to base34 encode the `$hash` to make it human readable.)

```
<?php
function int_hash($key) {
  $key = ($key^0x47cb8a8c) ^ ($key<<12);
  $key = ($key^0x61a988bc) ^ ($key>>19);
  $key = ($key^0x78d2a3c8) ^ ($key<<5);
  $key = ($key^0x5972b1be) ^ ($key<<9);
  $key = ($key^0x2ea72dfe) ^ ($key<<3);
  $key = ($key^0x5ff1057d) ^ ($key>>16);
  return $key;
}

for($order_id = 1; $order_id <= PHP_INT_MAX; ++$order_id) {
  $hash = int_hash($order_id);
}
?>
```

If not, are there any suggestions on how to replace `int_hash`?

The result of say, base34 encoding a `md5($order_id)` is too long for my liking.

Comment: What makes you think that they will be unique?  (aka "Why this particular algorithm?").

Comment: I was more hoping it would be. Perhaps I should have just straight out asked how I would go about creating a perfect hash function for a unsigned 32-bit int. I was hoping since they are just numbers that there would be a set of simple mathematical operations I could apply to them which would produce a 1:1 mapping.

Comment: All you need is a bit more than 8GiB of space (and of course some time) to answer your question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [php short hash](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/959957/php-short-hash)

Comment: @Leigh Thank you, a link in that question was quite helpful. I also came across Skip32 (a 32-bit block cipher based on Skipjack) during my own research which would seem to be suitable also.

Comment: @brightemo: With all hashes you're going to have a chance of collision though. I don't know of any that guarantee 2^32 unique combinations for 2^32 sequential inputs. I think you'd be better off with some sort of permutation table.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

> In my example code below, will every `$hash` be unique?

*Almost.* (Which, I guess, means "no, but in a way that's easily fixed".) Your function consists of a sequence of independent steps; the overall function is bijective (reversible) if and only if every single one of those steps is. (Do you see why?)

Now, each step has one of the following forms:

```
  $key = ($key ^ CONSTANT) ^ ($key >> NUM_BITS);
  $key = ($key ^ CONSTANT) ^ ($key << NUM_BITS);
```

with `NUM_BITS != 0`.

We can actually treat these as variants of a single form, by viewing the former as *almost* equivalent to this:

```
  $key = invert_order_of_bits($key); # clearly bijective
  $constant = invert_order_of_bits(CONSTANT);
  $key = ($key ^ $constant) ^ ($key << NUM_BITS);
  $key = invert_order_of_bits($key); # clearly bijective
```

So all we need is to show that this:

```
  $key = ($key ^ CONSTANT) ^ ($key << NUM_BITS);
```

is bijective. Now, XOR is commutative and associative, so the above is equivalent to this:

```
  $key = $key ^ ($key << NUM_BITS);
  $key = $key ^ CONSTANT;
```

and `(x ^ y) ^ y == x ^ (y ^ y) == x ^ 0 == x`, so clearly XOR-ing with a constant value is reversible (by re-XOR-ing with the same value); so all we have to show is that this is bijective:

```
  $key = $key ^ ($key << NUM_BITS);
```

whenever `NUM_BITS != 0`.

Now, I'm not writing a rigorous proof, so I'll just give a *single* reasoned-out example of how to reverse this. Suppose that `$key ^ ($key << 9)` is

```
0010 1010 1101 1110 0010 0101 0000 1100
```

How do we obtain `$key`? Well, we know that the last nine bits of `$key << 9` are all zeroes, so we know that the last nine bits of `$key ^ ($key << 9)` are the same as the last nine bits of `$key`. So `$key` looks like

```
bbbb bbbb bbbb bbbb bbbb bbb1 0000 1100
```

so `$key << 9` looks like

```
bbbb bbbb bbbb bb10 0001 1000 0000 0000
```

so `$key` looks like

```
bbbb bbbb bbbb bb00 0011 1101 0000 1100
```

(by XOR-ing `$key ^ ($key << 9)` with `$key << 9`), so `$key << 9` looks like

```
bbbb b000 0111 1010 0001 1000 0000 0000
```

so `$key` looks like

```
bbbb b010 1010 0100 0011 1101 0000 1100
```

so `$key << 9` looks like

```
0101 1000 0111 1010 0001 1000 0000 0000
```

so `$key` looks like

```
0111 0010 1010 0100 0011 1101 0000 1100
```

So . . . why do I say "almost" rather than "yes"? Why is your hash-function not *perfectly* bijective? It's because in PHP, the bitwise shift operators `>>` and `<<` are not *quite* symmetric, and while `$key = $key ^ ($key << NUM_BITS)` is completely reversible, `$key = $key ^ ($key >> NUM_BITS)` is not. (Above, when I wrote that the two types of steps were "*almost* equivalent", I really *meant* that "almost". It makes a difference!) You see, whereas `<<` treats the sign bit just like any other bit, and shifts it out of existence (bringing in a zero-bit on the right), `>>` treats the sign bit specially, and "extends" it: the bit that it brings in on the left is equal to the sign bit. (N.B. Your question mentions "unsigned 32bit" values, but PHP doesn't actually support that; its bitwise operations are always on *signed* integers.)

Due to this sign extension, if `$key` starts with a `0`, then `$key >> NUM_BITS` starts with a `0`, and if `$key` starts with a `1`, then `$key >> NUM_BITS` also starts with a `1`. In either case, `$key ^ ($key >> NUM_BITS)` will start with a `0`. You've lost exactly one bit of entropy. If you give me `$key ^ ($key >> 9)`, and don't tell me whether `$key` is negative, then the best I can do is compute two possible values for `$key`: one negative, one positive-or-zero.

You perform two steps that use right-shift instead of left-shift, so you lose two bits of entropy. (I'm hand-waving slightly — all I've actually demonstrated is that you lose *at least* one bit and *at most* two bits — but I'm confident that, due to the nature of the steps between those right-shift steps, you do actually lose two full bits.) For any given output value, there are exactly four distinct input-values that could yield it. So it's not unique, but it's *almost* unique; and it's easily fixed, by either:

- changing the two right-shift steps to use left-shifts instead; or
- moving both of the right-shift steps to the start of the function, before any left-shift steps, and saying that outputs are unique for inputs between 0 and 2<sup>31</sup>−1 rather than inputs between 0 and 2<sup>32</sup>−1.

Comment: An impressive answer indeed. Although I got slightly lost in the 2nd from last paragraph. Might want to slip a line break or two in there :)

Comment: Thank you, that was very helpful! My brain keeps telling me that it can not possibly be unique, it is just too simple. (Other solutions I have seen are using some form of encryption, lookup tables, or multiplication by prime numbers, see [link](http://blog.kevburnsjr.com/php-unique-hash)).

Comment: @brightemo: You're welcome! I was also really surprised. At first, when I'd just started working through the logic, I completely expected to find a way to generate collisions, rather than to find an argument for why there aren't any. :-P